# Gmail still deleting email!

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I had a filter in place to delete a Gmail group address. I have since joined this group email, and have deleted the filter, but Gmail still deletes emails from that address.

Comment: It's likely another remaining filter performing the action.  Additional detail about your problem space would be helpful.  Look at any remaining filters closely.  You can test them by removing a message from trash, then using any filters that you suspect might be culprits, see if the msg is returned in a search: [Edit Filters](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#settings/filters) > ``Edit`` > ``Search``